# Yahoo Calendar API in Java

Tags: java, javascript, api, jsp

Is there any java API is available for Yahoo calendar? I want to programmatically login to an user account and needs to read his/her calendar appointments. I want to integrate google, yahoo and hotmail calendars with my web application. I know there is an API for google. I didn't find a good example to yahoo calendar api. Please let me know how to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo does support CalDAV via https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com and a quick google brings up the following libraries for Java:

- [caldav4j](http://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/)
- [ical4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page)

For more info on the protocol itself, visit http://caldav.calconnect.org/index.html

Unfortunately this is not nearly as friendly as google's REST API but it's at least possible. I don't know if I personally would go to the trouble.